# How do I solve for $x$ in $ab^x-cd^x=e$?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

For example: I know that $5*1.2^{13}-8*1.1^{13}\approx26$. How do I find the exponential value (13 in the previous example) that would equate to 26 exactly? The answer should be something close to 13.017, but I cannot figure out the precise formula that solves for the exponential value.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it's possible?

Comment: It seems solvable only because I can get an increasingly accurate value for x through incremental tinkering. I thought I might be able to use the log function to get x out of the exponent, but I wasn't able to get any traction with that approach.

Comment: Would an infinite series count as an expression for the value? (NB I'm not offering to find one.) A nice (or even nasty) formula doesn't seem likely.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a clean analytic solution.  Your incremental tinkering is evidence that a solution exists and that standard numerical algorithms will find it; it is not evidence for the existence of a simple analytic expression for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most general case, you will not get any analytical solution for the equation
$$ab^x-cd^x=e$$ and some numerical method (Newton would be the simplest) would be required. For the exercise, let us assume that all coefficients $a,b,c,d$ are positive and consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=ab^x-cd^x-e$$ It is not very well consitioned since each term can vary very fast. So, instead, consider the function
$$g(x)=\log(a b^x)-\log(cd^x+e)=\log(a)+x \log(b)-\log(cd^x+e)$$ which will look like a straight line.

Because ot that, we can start Newton using $x_0=0$ and get as a first estimate
$$x_1=-\frac{\log (a)-\log (c+e)}{\log (b)-\frac{c }{c+e}\log (d)}$$

Using your numbers,  the first iterate would be $11.9886$ and the successive iterates would be (with a ridiculous number of figures)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 11.988586471043999070 \\
 2 & 13.008178802782428286 \\
 3 & 13.017039083216507506 \\
 4 & 13.017039751873577944 \\
 5 & 13.017039751873581752
\end{array}
\right)$$

Just to make it more funny, let us keep all your numbers but change $e=26$ to $e=123456789$. Doing the same,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 93.362325303012764401 \\
 2 & 93.364923494763192368 \\
 3 & 93.364923494842914130
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Although it was doubted that there is a nice expression in general, there is a nice formula for the case $a=c$.

So we consider the following transcendental equation and try to find the solution $z=z(t)$,
$$t=e^{\alpha z}(e^{\beta z}-1)\tag{1}$$
Take $\phi(z)=ze^{-\alpha z}(e^{\beta z}-1)^{-1}$, rewrite $(1)$ as
$$z=t\phi(z)\tag{2}$$
Apply [Langrange inversion theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), take $g(z)=z$,
\begin{align*}
g(z)=z&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left\{\frac{\mathrm d^{n-1}}{\mathrm dz^{n-1}}\big[\phi(z)\big]^n\right\}_{z=0} t^n\\
&=\frac 1\beta\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}\left\{\frac{\mathrm d^{n-1}}{\mathrm dz^{n-1}}e^{-n\alpha z/\beta}\left(\frac z{e^z-1}\right)^n\right\}_{z=0} t^n.
\end{align*}
Since 
$$\left(\frac z{e^z-1}\right)^ne^{\gamma z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}B_k^{(n)}(\gamma)z^k,$$
where $B_k^{(n)}(x)$ is the generalized Bernoulli polynomial,
$$B_k^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(n-1)!}{k!}\frac{\mathrm d^{n-k-1}}{\mathrm dx^{n-k-1}}[(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n+1)],\quad k<n,$$
therefore,
\begin{align*}
B_{n-1}^{(n)}\left(-\frac{n\alpha}\beta\right)&=\left\{\frac{\mathrm d^{n-1}}{\mathrm dz^{n-1}}e^{-n\alpha z/\beta}\left(\frac z{e^z-1}\right)^n\right\}_{z=0}\\
&=\left(-\frac{n\alpha}\beta-1\right)\left(-\frac{n\alpha}\beta-2\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{n\alpha}\beta-n+1\right)\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{n\alpha}\beta+1\right)_{n-1}\equiv \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n\frac\beta\alpha\left(\frac{n\alpha}\beta\right)_n.
\end{align*}
We get a nice expression (in series) of the solution for $(1)$,

> $$z=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n!}\frac1{n\alpha}\left(\frac{n\alpha}\beta\right)_n t^n.\tag{3}$$

---

In your general case with $a=c$,
$$a\cdot b^x-c\cdot d^x=e,$$
the answer is given by setting $t=\frac ea$, $\alpha=\ln d$, $\beta=\ln(\frac bd)$ in $(3)$.